# List of installed apps from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play-services

I've looked at various sources but can't find an answer either way.  Is it possible to query the Google Play Store to see if an app has been installed by an account, even if it has been removed from the device?  I know how to do this using my own web service, but I'd prefer to not have a separate web service out there that basically duplicates information stored by Google.

The scenario in which I see this being most useful is if a user nukes/reformats the device, then logs in and downloads old apps again.  I want to know if the app has already been downloaded so that I can bypass some initial setup tasks (account creation, tutorials, etc.) when they run it the first time again.  I'll admit it is a bit of a niche situation, but for functionality I'd like to provide it if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the Cloud Save feature of Google Play Services for this functionality.  [Google Description of Cloud Save implementation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/cloudsave)

When the user first logs in to my program, I use getAppStateClient().listStates to see if the State Key even exists (for me, sometimes it does not "auto" tell me that the State Key Doesn't exist, so I don't rely on that functionality)

If the key doesn't exist, then I know they've never used the program before, so, then I can add the key with whatever value (for you, perhaps only add the key after they have completed the login/setup process... or whatever would work for your flow)

If the key does exist, then I have different values that I store there to tell me what prior information the user has entered  (for you, could set if they completed Login Process or not, last time they logged in... etc)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I think this addresses a different issue.  I am trying to limit the amount of additional state/business logic I need to implement.  Perhaps it isn't possible, but I presume that the list of apps associated with a given Play account are publicly accessible from a person's device, so I just want to be able to query the Play database and see if the user on this "fresh" device already paid for the application within the store, which should be available.  I can always create a check on my local server, but that seems to duplicate functionality.